# BT Home Hub as Wireless AP

Tags: router, wireless-router

I have recently left some accommodation where we were using a BT Home Hub 5 (Type A) Router.  We've cancelled the contract with BT and they advised we don't need to sent the router back to them - win!!

However, I would like to re-purpose the router and make it either a Wireless Access Point (Bridged to the existing router in my new accommodation), or flash the router with something like OpenWRT.

I've Google'd about and can't see anything regarding setting these devices to Bridged Mode, or flashing them with other firmware.

Has anyone managed to set one of these to Bridged mode, or flash them with other firmware at all?

Comment: Check out the following links, they might help: http://www.filesaveas.com/hubhelp.html, http://www.filesaveas.com/cgi-bin/forum/YaBB.pl?board=homehub

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill I will take a look.  Clearly my Google Fu wasn't strong enough for this one! :)

Comment: No problem. I still had the links stashed away since a job a few years ago when I was supporting VoIP ;)

Comment: From user [Hobbo91](http://superuser.com/users/553231/hobbo91): I also plan to flash the openWRT firmware to a HomeHub 5, but I cannot for the life of me find anyone on google who has actually done this.  Was the Router stable when flashed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no third-party firmware for the HomeHub 5 that I'm aware of, partly because of the encrypted and secured firmware update process BT use that makes it awkwardly difficult to even get started.

As for bridge mode, the LAN and wireless is always working in bridge mode anyway. To use it as an AP just turn off DHCP. *Wireless* bridging, e.g. WDS, is currently not possible.

[Edit]

As of September 2015, there's now partial, experimental support for the device but still requires physical modification to actually upload the firmware.

Comment: Thanks for that @qasdfdsaq.  I will keep an eye online for any future firmware upgrades :)

Comment: *** UPDATE *** I have managed to get OpenWRT onto my HomeHub 5 Type A device.  http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/bt/homehub_v5a  It does require some soldering to create a Serial to USB Connection to be able to backup & upload the firmware, so not easy, however this does work.

Comment: @James: Very interesting to know. I'll be keeping an eye on developments.

Comment: @qasdfdasq cool,  I will be using this as a Wireless Bridge and possibly an access point at the same time while at Uni, so I will let you know how we get on.

Comment: @James: From what I know the ath10k driver for QCA9880 under OpenWRT is very unstable right now, but you may have better luck than me.